# Directing a user to an appropriate log in form

Tags: forms, login, registration, signup-signon

Hypothetically, a business has a suite of 10 products, each with separate domains. This business has separate 4 user groups who achieve different tasks on each product. Some products are made for only one user group, other products are made for all. Each product must have a separate login/registration form.

In a global sense, what is the quickest way for a user to be directed to their appropriate product and either register (as a new user) or log in (as a registered user)?

Comment: Like Stack Exchange?

Comment: Why should the user create different accounts on every product? Multi-products companies usually use a Single Sign-On approach to tackle this (see Zoho, Google, Atlassian...)

Answer (score 1):

You are better doing this using database tables. Each time a user logs in you determine which group they belong to, group 1, 2, 3 or 4 based on the registration information they have given you. Your database tables for each of the 10 products would also show which groups can have access to it.

So once a user logs in, you determine from the database table which group they belong to. You then direct them to the page with the products they can work on after checking the products database tables.

Yes I agree this is not a UI question.

Answer (score 0):

- you can save user group/domain at the time of account creation and direct him to that channel,
- give an option(dropdown) to choose among the domains/groups either at the time of login or once logged-in.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Facebook login]

You could have something like this for the Landing page of each product, with the sign in and register forms upfront.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a server-side piece, rather than a front end UX component.

Some of this will depend on the environment, and other parts will depend on security considerations.

On an intranet site using IIS, you could use Active Directory (AD) groups to define login domain and product access.

Security considerations will define how you set this up on an internet site.  If it's imperative that users can't get access to sections where they don't belong, it'd be logical to setup a registration-by-invitation system where the user and their access is setup by an admin before they're invited to complete their account registration.  Otherwise, allowing users to select their own groups at login in appropriate.

Either way, the most efficient method of directing users to the appropriate content is to have a single login form that uses server-side coding at login to redirect users to the appropriate content and set security credentials/permissions to ensure that users aren't able to access incorrect content.